# Any difference between W2 by mail and W2 by e-mail?

Tags: united-states, form-w-2

I have been filing taxes from the last 2 years in USA. For both of my pervious tax filling I have got W2 forms by mail which looked similar to the following forms.

[image: w2 - sample]

[image]

They were both sent by mail and they were either individual forms for each copy like the first one or a perforated form like the second one. In both cases the font size was fine and legible. This year I got the W2 form sent to me as a PDF by email. Its looks similar to the following form.

[image]

So here are my questions

- Will it be fine if I print this year's W2 form I got by email and use it for tax filling or should I request my employer to send one by mail? Is there any difference between the two?
- I tried to print the W2 form which I got as a single page PDF on the standard letter size paper and the font size is small and not very legible. Will it be fine if I print the form in parts like two landscape prints instead of a single portrait print?

Just want to confirm I am doing it the right way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The IRS is flexible regarding W-2 forms. The employer can use a variety of formats. If you use online or software to fill out the tax forms, you may be able to download the numbers without typing. If you file electronically the IRS never sees the paper version.

Comment: I am a non resident alien hence I can't file electronically. So I can print out the W2 form and file my taxes right?

Comment: Yes. The paper forms tell you where to attach W-2s and other forms. It doesn't matter if they mailed you the forms or you downloaded them and printed them.